# Taking screenshots of my React-Native app using fastlane

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, fastlane

Working on publishing my first RN app. I'm using fastlane to make life easier. Working on getting snapshots following this guide: [screenshots](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/screenshots/#capture-screenshots-automatically). But I don't know what this means:

> To take a screenshot, call the following between interactions
>
> 1. Swift: snapshot("01LoginScreen") . . .

How do I "call" that swift line in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to write a UITest "script" that is executed. The easiest way to create one is by using a recorder, as described here for example: https://krausefx.com/blog/run-xcode-7-ui-tests-from-the-command-line

In the resulting test file you then call `snapshot(...)` to execute a screenshot at the correct time. (It is all documented on the page you posted, further down.)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! Now I gotta get it to not freeze while recording (old macbook).

Comment: I know that struggle ;)

Comment: I think it's not freezing actually, that xcode is just not recording a bunch of my interactions. BACK TO GOOGLE!

Comment: That is very possible - I did the same thing with a few Cordova based apps and writing these tests really is its own science...